# Переформатирование документа

Tags: python

Имеется большой txt файл, который содержит 2 цифровых значения - 1 и 2. Но записаны они в следующем виде:

`10*1 2 5*1 7*2 1 5*2` и т.д.

Как я могу их вывести в вид:
`1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 5 5 5 5 5` и т.д.

Заранее, большое спасибо!

Comment: Распарсить и обработать. Значения разделены пробелами, так что считывайте текст, делаете разделение по пробелам, перебираете получившиеся части строк и для каждой проверяйте если ли там `*`, если есть, то снова делаете разделение на два элемента, генерируете строку по символам. Добавьте в вопрос свою попытку решения, так будет проще вам помочь :)

Comment: @gil9red спасибо большое) Буду пробовать!

Comment: Пожалуйста, если есть вопросы или возникнут проблемы, то добавьте код и напишите в комментарии

Comment: @gil9red спасибо за Вашу доброжелательность) У меня вроде как получилось - использовал сплит для всего файла, после нашел звездочки в каждом элементе и от них уже разделил так, как мне нужно. Сейчас осталось добавить пробелы в получившиеся строки (там сейчас вместо 1 1 1 - 111) и все) Но с этим справлюсь. Еще раз спасибо Вам!

Comment: Вы молодец, что сами с этим справляетесь :) Пробелы просто добавить, если заранее сгенерировать коллекцию и применить к ней `join`, например для 5 единиц: `print(" ".join('1' for _ in range(5)))` или через умножение списка `print(" ".join(['1'] * 5))`